# PFInstallation Not Fetching All Columns

Tags: ios, parse-platform

When I use `[PFInstallation currentInstallation]`, not all columns from the parse database are fetched. And even the columns that are fetched do not even contain all the correct data. For example I have a subscribedTags column on my Installation class, which holds an array of strings, and in the data browser I can see that there are 5 strings contained in the array, however when I call `NSLog(@"%@", [PFInstallation currentInstallation]);` only 3 strings are logged as belonging to the installation. This is clearly untrue by inspecting the data browser.

Is this a bug with parse? Might there be any way to work around this to guarantee that my PFInstallation returns me all the correct values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell the current installation data is not automatically fetched from parse's servers, so I needed to add `[[PFInstallation currentInstallation] fetch];` to get the most up-to-date data on the current installation. I chose to add this in the `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application` method in my AppDelegate.m file so that every time the user opens the app his/her current installation will be up to date.

Note this method can block the main queue, so it might be a good idea to call it on a separate thread.

Comment: Don't need to fetch in main thread, you can fetch in background too. `[[PFInstallation currentInstallation] fetchInBackground];`